# Etymology of the word "Aberglaube"

Tags: etymology, english

I am interested in the etymology of the German word "*Aberglaube*".  As an anglophone, this word for '*superstition*' has an interesting literal translation into English.

**I am curious about the etymology of this word.**

A comparison to the English translation would be much appreciated as well, but not required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberglaube#Begriffsgeschichte) explains:

> Der Begriff Aberglaube ist seit dem 15. Jahrhundert belegt (abergloube). Der Wortbestandteil „aber-“ bedeutete nach Auffassung heutiger etymologischer Wörterbücher ursprünglich „nach, wider, hinter“, wobei es später eine abschätzige Bedeutung annahm und das Gegenteil dessen bezeichnete, was der zweite Wortbestandteil ausdrückte, z. B. bei „Aberwitz“.[4](http://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/aberglaube) Das Wort kam als Lehnübertragung des lateinischen Begriffs super-stitio in Gebrauch.[5](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aberglaube) Er stand für „falsche“, d. h. von der christlichen Glaubenslehre abweichende, Glaubensinhalte und -formen.

The *Aber* had a old meaning *nach* or *hinter* (after), [*wider* (against)](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=wider). So it is the "wrong" (not Christian) belief.

The [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Aberglaube) has the same explanation, on [wissen.de](http://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/aberglaube) it is:

> (ältere Form auch Afterglaube) Glaube an Kräfte und Geschehnisse, die der gewohnten Erfahrung und den Naturgesetzen oder der kirchlichen Lehre widersprechen ♦ aus mhd. abe „weg von“ und Glaube, also „falscher, abweichender Glaube“

There exists also an older version *Afterglaube*

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aberglaube) translates the Middle High German *aber* with *wrong*.:

> von mittelhochdeutsch: abergloube[1](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberglaube#Begriffsgeschichte), einer Zusammensetzung aus mittelhochdeutsch: aber - verkehrt und gloube, geloube - „Glaube“

Answer (score 3):

In order to second knut's answer here are a couple of more quotes:

> Aberglaube m., (selten) Aberglauben ‘in falschen Vorstellungen wurzelnder Glaube, Irrglaube, trügerische Vorstellung, Einbildung, Vorurteil’, spätmhd. abergloube, doch geläufig erst seit Ende des 15. Jhs. In Zusammensetzungen dieses Typs (s. auch unten  Aberwitz) bezeichnet aber-, ausgehend von der wiederholenden Funktion, das Gegenteil oder unechte Gegenstück des im Grundwort genannten Begriffs. abergläubisch Adj. ‘im Aberglauben befangen, dem Aberglauben entspringend’ (Anfang 16. Jh.), älter (heute ungebräuchlich) abergläubig (Ende 15. Jh.); vgl. mnd. āver(ge)lȫvich, (häufiger) āver(ge)lȫvisch. <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=aberglaube)</sup>
>
> aberglaube, m. superstitio, für oberglaube, nnl. overgeloof, überglaube, dem super in superstitio nachgebildet, nd. biglove, beiglaube, böhm. powẽra, von po bei und wẽra glaube, ahd. ubarfengida, was über den wahren glauben hinaus, daran neben vorbei geht. Lessing 3, 216 setzt fehlerhaft den acc. aberglaube f. aberglauben, wie umgekehrt andere den nom. aberglauben f. aberglaube. <sup>[Grimmsche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA00348)</sup>

And regarding the English word

> superstitious (adj.)
> late 14c., from Old French superstitieux, from Latin superstitiosus, from superstitionem (nominative superstitio) "prophecy, soothsaying, excessive fear of the gods," perhaps originally "state of religious exaltation," related to superstes (genitive superstitis) "standing over or above," also "standing by, surviving," from superstare "stand on or over, survive," from super "above" (see super-) + stare "to stand," from PIE root *sta- "to stand" (see stet). There are many theories for the Latin sense development, but none has yet triumphed. <sup>[Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=superstitious)</sup>